# Referring to an object defined by a variable

Tags: c#

I have a problem, which I couldn't solve recently.
I have this code

```
        foreach (Hashtable i in (ArrayList)inv["database"])
        {
            if (i != null)
            {
                if (i["type"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    if (i["dataValue"].ToString() != "0")
                    {
                        inv{nn}.Image = Program.Properties.Resources._i["type"].ToString()+"-"+i["dataValue"].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        inv{nn}.Image = Program.Properties.Resources._i["type"].ToString()
                    }
                }
            }
            nn++;
        }
```

I have 36 controls(it's a class i have in my project, so not "vanilla" one), and each one of them is a single "picturebox". I have 505 images in the following syntax:
If the data value is 0, then it's {typeID}.png, if the data value is above 0, then {typeID}-{dataValue}.png

So for example if it's the first loop,  i["type"].ToString() = 1 and i["dataValue"].ToString() = 3, the Image of inv0 changes to Program.Proporties.Resources._1-3
When the second loop comes the image of inv1 changes etc. ... till inv35

Is such thing possible? I tried

```
InterpolationBox x = Form1.FindControl("inv"+nn)
```

and I seem not to have such thing as FindControl (FrameWork 4) with System.Web.UI used.

I tried

```
InterpolationBox x = this.Controls.Find("inv" + nn, false);
```

And I got Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to type 'Program.InterpolatedBox'. And anyway, if I'd get rid of that error, would I be able to change that actual picturebox, not just the copied 'x' one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InterpolationBox x = this.Controls.Find("inv" + nn, false);
```

Is where your problem lies.

The error you got is telling:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to type
>   'Program.InterpolatedBox'.

You can see it's saying it can't cast an array of `System.Windows.Forms.Control` to a `Program.InterpolationBox` which is sensible given `InterpolationBox` is a single control.

The `Find` method returns an array of controls, not just one, so you need to then look in the array and pull out the one you're after (even if it's just the first one).

---

As for your question about whether changing `x` would change the control you got given using `Controls.Find()` the answer is YES.

Objects in .NET are by reference, which means `x` isn't an `InterpolationBox` it's a reference to an `InterpolationBox` in memory.

You could even do:

```
var a = x;
var b = a;
var c = b;

c.DoSomething();
```

The code you call against `c` will operate against the same object, they're all just references pointing to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so how can I get that InterpolationBox out of this Array? And, like, can I do a similar thing to Resources?

Comment: InterpolationBox x = this.Controls.Find("inv" + nn, false).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: That will return the first control it found, or null, so you need to check x for null before using it, you can adopt your own decisions for how you want to find the control you're after, it's an array so you can just look through it and find one. As for resources I'm not sure, I'd look at the resource documentation on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. And I solved the problem with resources using
obj = RM.GetObject(i["type"].ToString() + "-" + i["dataValue"].ToString());
where RM was:
ResourceManager RM = new ResourceManager("MyProgram.Properties.Resources", Assembly.Load("MyProgram"));